# Disable slicer effects selectively

Tags: powerbi

Is it possible to disable the slicer effects on certain reports but keeping them alive on some other reports (**all reports are on the same page**).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have the slicer disabled on some report while being active on the others.

> > First select the concerned slicer.
> >
> > Then, go to the **Format** tab on top and click on **Edit Interactions**.
> >
> > You can then see a funnel and a cross mark over all the reports/ Slicers on the page. Click on the cross mark to disable slicer effects on the report. Click on the funnel sign to re-activate.